# Not able to add UIImageView to MainViewController in ios Cordova?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview, uiimageview

Iam trying to add a `UIImageView` on top of `MainViewController` and when i run the project `UIImageView` is not there.

Infact if i add a plain `UIVIew` i can see the new view, but not UIButton or `UIImageView`.

I have added this code to init method to bring the `UIImageView` to front but not working

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self.webView bringSubviewToFront:self.moxiView];
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandDelegateImpl used
        // _commandDelegate = [[MainCommandDelegate alloc] initWithViewController:self];
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandQueue used
        // _commandQueue = [[MainCommandQueue alloc] initWithViewController:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Check attached screenshots[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm7Fa.png)

How can i add UIImageView on cordova "MainViewController" file ?